# How to make one hyperlink give different pages?

Tags: html

I'm trying to set up a hyperlink that will randomly open a different webpage per click from a list of URLs. Does anyone know what would be a good function to start with to achieve this?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: A good function to start ? there is one that is very used begin(); ,try it ,maybe works

Comment: This can be done with JavaScript, or server side script like PHP etc. but not just with html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
var links = ['http://google.com', 'http://facebook.com']
function GoToSomeAddress() {
    window.open(links[getRandomInt(0, 1)]);
}

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
The content of the body element is displayed in your browser.
<a href="" onclick="GoToSomeAddress();return false;">Take me on an adventure</a>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: getRandomInt should get the links sizes and use them,doesn't need params

Comment: This is perfect, thank you! I was looking for an example like this on the internet but couldn't find it.

Comment: @O.Rares This is code provided by Mozilla for random number in range, obviously you can refactor and move things around, this is the basic template though.